# C# mongodb driver Command aggregate failed Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I try to execute query with c# mongodb driver (MongoDB.Driver.2.0.1),

```
dbCollection.Aggregate().Match(query).Sort(sort Definition).Skip(startIndex - 1).Limit(count).ToListAsync().Result
```

it is drops with error : `"Command aggregate failed: exception: Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes, but did not opt in to external sorting. Aborting operation. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in..."`

When I added an option allowDiskUse = true, it execute successful

```
dbCollection.Aggregate(new Aggregated Options{AllowDiskUse=true}).Match(query).Sort(sort Definition).Skip(startIndex - 1).Limit(count).ToListAsync().Result
```

But, I want to understand, its query execute on server? Because when i execute its query in robomongo (on server) with limit, it does not drop, but when I done this query without limit, it is drop.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#agg-memory-restrictions you should probably look at changing your logic if your query is using up that much RAM.

Comment: Yes. my request consumes a lot of memory, but I thought, if I add the limit, it will solve the problem. But it seems to me that first fulfills a match, then from the result is taken limit. I thought the whole aggregation will work in the database